# Passing each element of a parsed sequence to a function that returns a rule's attribute type

Tags: c++, css, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I want to parse CSS color functions (for simplicity, all of the arguments are numbers between 0 and 255)

```
rgb(r,g,b)
rgba(r,g,b,a)
hsl(h,s,l)
hsla(h,s,l,a)
```

into

```
struct color
{
    color(std::uint8_t r, std::uint8_t g, std::uint8_t b, std::uint8_t a) : red{r}, green{g}, blue{b}, alpha{a} {}
    static color hsl(std::uint8_t h, std::uint8_t s, std::uint8_t l, std::uint8_t a) { ... }
    std::uint8_t red;
    std::uint8_t green;
    std::uint8_t blue;
    std::uint8_t alpha;
}
```

I have a working `hsl` function implementation that converts the h, s, and l into rgb values.

I also have `rule`s to handle the first two functions:

```
constexpr auto uint8 = uint_parser<std::uint8_t>{};
const auto color_rgb = rule<struct rgb, color>{"rgb"}
                     = lit("rgb") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ')' >> attr(255);
const auto color_rgba = rule<struct rgba, color>{"rgba"}
                      = lit("rgba") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ')';
```

This works because I have used

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(color,
                          red, green, blue, alpha)
```

The problem lies in the `hsl` functions. I cannot do a second `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`, so I thought of using semantic actions on the respective sequences of values where the semantic action would simply construct the `color` from the sequence. Something like this:

```
const auto color_hsl = rule<struct hsl, color, true>{"hsl"}
                   = (lit("hsl") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ')' >> attr(255))[color::hsl];
```

This doesn't work, or I wouldn't be asking this question. Neither does Boost.Spirit.X3 have something in the sense of

```
[ qi::_val = phx::construct<color>(...), qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4) ];
```

It seems I want to do manually what `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` does, but in a semantic action. Is this possible and how should I handle this? I know the attribute of the sequence should be an "fusion-vector" tuple-like entity with the four parsed values. I want to extract them and stuff them into `color::hsl` to generate the rule's attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many hints apply here.

1. > I cannot do a second BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT

   Sure you can, see [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_NAMED`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct_named.html)
2. In Qi this general form seem to apply:

   ```
   [ qi::_val = phxfunction(qi::_0) ]
   ```

   You could further simplify that by making your own actor type so you could just supply your "factory action": `[ factory(&Foo::makeBar) ]`.

   If you throw in an implementation of `fusion::apply`¹ you can avoid ever dealing with the Fusion sequence manuallt
3. However, you might want to learn about this - very well hidden - attribute compatibility mode for semantic actions: [`BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_2_5.html#spirit.what_s_new.spirit_2_5.making_stuff_work). Buried in that change log:

   > Semantic actions now support attribute compatibility. This is a breaking change but #define `BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT` must be defined in order for the new behavior to kick in. *By default, the old behavior is still in place*.

   You might get the behaviour you desire with much less tweaking.
4. X3 is really malleable. We can have that `factory` helper described above in as little as:

   ```
   auto factory = [](auto f) {
       return [f](auto& ctx) {
           x3::_val(ctx) = my_apply(f, x3::_attr(ctx));
       };
   };
   ```

   I'll throw in a quick draft of `my_apply` (for the `boost::fusion::apply` described earlier):

   ```
   namespace detail {
       template <class F, class Sequence, std::size_t... I>
           constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Sequence&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
           {
               return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), boost::fusion::at_c<I>(std::forward<Sequence>(t))...);
           }
   }

   template <class F, class Sequence>
       constexpr decltype(auto) my_apply(F&& f, Sequence&& t)
       {
           return detail::apply_impl(
                   std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Sequence>(t),
                   std::make_index_sequence<typename boost::fusion::result_of::size<std::remove_reference_t<Sequence> >::type{}>{});
       }
   ```

Now we can have the parser:

```
namespace parser {
    using namespace x3;

    constexpr auto uint8  = uint_parser<std::uint8_t>{};

    auto factory = [](auto f) {
        return [f](auto& ctx) {
            x3::_val(ctx) = my_apply(f, x3::_attr(ctx));
        };
    };

    const auto color_rgb  = rule<struct rgb, ast::color>{"rgb"}
                          = lit("rgb") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> x3::attr(255u) >> ')';
    const auto color_rgba = rule<struct rgba, ast::color>{"rgba"}
                          = lit("rgba") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ')';
    const auto color_hsl  = rule<struct hsl, ast::color>{"hsl"}
                          = (lit("hsl") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> attr(255u) >> ')') [factory(ast::color::hsl)];

    const auto color = skip(space) [ color_rgba | color_rgb | color_hsl ];
}
```

And test it with:

```
int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
            "rgb(1,2,3)",
            "rgba(4,5,6,7)",
            "hsl(8,9,10)" }) 
    {
        std::cout << " ----- Parsng " << std::quoted(input) << " --------\n";
        auto begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();

        ast::color result;
        bool success = parse(begin, end, parser::color, result);

        if (success) {
            std::cout << "parsed: ";
            std::cout << result << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "failed\n";
        }

        if (begin != end) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(begin, end)) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/254a4562461334ba)</kbd>**

```
 ----- Parsng "rgb(1,2,3)" --------
parsed: rgba(1,2,3,255)
 ----- Parsng "rgba(4,5,6,7)" --------
parsed: rgba(4,5,6,7)
 ----- Parsng "hsl(8,9,10)" --------
TODO: implement static ast::color ast::color::hsl(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)(8,9,10,255)
parsed: rgba(8,9,10,255)
```

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/254a4562461334ba)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/size.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;


namespace ast {
    using std::uint8_t;

    struct color {
        uint8_t red, green, blue, alpha;

        color(uint8_t r=0, uint8_t g=0, uint8_t b=0, uint8_t a=255) : red{r}, green{g}, blue{b}, alpha{a} {}

        static color hsl(uint8_t h, uint8_t s, uint8_t l, uint8_t a) { 
            std::cerr << "TODO: implement " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << 1*h << "," << 1*s << "," << 1*l << "," << 1*a << ")\n";
            return {h,s,l,a}; }
    };

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, color const& c) {
        return os << "rgba(" << 1*c.red << "," << 1*c.green << "," << 1*c.blue << "," << 1*c.alpha << ")";
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::color, red, green, blue, alpha);

namespace {
    namespace detail {
        template <class F, class Sequence, std::size_t... I>
            constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Sequence&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
            {
                return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), boost::fusion::at_c<I>(std::forward<Sequence>(t))...);
            }
    }

    template <class F, class Sequence>
        constexpr decltype(auto) my_apply(F&& f, Sequence&& t)
        {
            return detail::apply_impl(
                    std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Sequence>(t),
                    std::make_index_sequence<typename boost::fusion::result_of::size<std::remove_reference_t<Sequence> >::type{}>{});
        }
}

namespace parser {
    using namespace x3;

    constexpr auto uint8  = uint_parser<std::uint8_t>{};

    auto factory = [](auto f) {
        return [f](auto& ctx) {
            x3::_val(ctx) = my_apply(f, x3::_attr(ctx));
        };
    };

    const auto color_rgb  = rule<struct rgb, ast::color>{"rgb"}
                          = lit("rgb") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> x3::attr(255u) >> ')';
    const auto color_rgba = rule<struct rgba, ast::color>{"rgba"}
                          = lit("rgba") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ')';
    const auto color_hsl  = rule<struct hsl, ast::color>{"hsl"}
                          = (lit("hsl") >> '(' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> ',' >> uint8 >> attr(255u) >> ')') [factory(ast::color::hsl)];

    const auto color = skip(space) [ color_rgba | color_rgb | color_hsl ];
} 

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
            "rgb(1,2,3)",
            "rgba(4,5,6,7)",
            "hsl(8,9,10)" }) 
    {
        std::cout << " ----- Parsng " << std::quoted(input) << " --------\n";
        auto begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();

        ast::color result;
        bool success = parse(begin, end, parser::color, result);

        if (success) {
            std::cout << "parsed: ";
            std::cout << result << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "failed\n";
        }

        if (begin != end) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(begin, end)) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

¹ it seems not to exist. Of course you could copy to a `std::tuple` and use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) (also [experimental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply))

Comment: Awesome stuff thanks! I'm hitting some other issues (unrelated to this question) right now or I'd show you the result I came up with. I'm still not comfortable with Spirit. Seems like the documentation could easily be expanded tenfold to give people some grip to not continuously shoot themselves in their own feet... I'm getting the impression that I'm relying too much on semantic actions though.

Comment: FYI: this is [my current working code](https://github.com/skui-org/skui/blob/2b6b06694b73c07af5095a848faa5e1cb9be8fd6/css/grammar/color.h%2B%2B). I had to juggle types and semantic actions for it to work mostly like https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp. I'm quite satisfied but there are still some changes that I tried that completely break it. Tests are [here](https://github.com/skui-org/skui/blob/2b6b06694b73c07af5095a848faa5e1cb9be8fd6/tests/css/grammar/color.test.c%2B%2B).